# Python libpcap wrapper that understands pcap-ng format?

Tags: python, wireshark, libpcap

Have any of the existing libpcap wrappers for python been updated to read the pcap-ng format generated by Wireshark 1.8.x? I tried several of them with no success. Maybe I'm missing something, like config options or new APIs.

If this hasn't been done yet or is incomplete, I'm willing to help with the work. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1):

What needs to be updated is libpcap, not the wrapper.  Libpcap 1.1.0 and later can transparently read pcap-ng files, as long as the pcap-ng files don't have more than one link-layer header type (for example, a pcap-ng file with two LINKTYPE_ETHERNET interfaces would be readable, but a pcap-ng file with a LINKTYPE_ETHERNET interface and a LINKTYPE_PPP interface wouldn't be).

Reading *arbitrary* pcap-ng files would require API changes to libpcap; the wrappers would then have to pick up those changes as well.

Comment: To your knowledge, is this on anyone's roadmap?

Comment: It's something I want to do, but I don't know when it'll happen.

Comment: Can I help? I'm an experienced C/C++ programmer and I lead a team of people who can also help.

Comment: Yes.  [Join the tcpdump-workers mailing list](http://www.tcpdump.org/#mailing-lists) (it's for tcpdump and libpcap users and developers), [use Git to get at the libpcap and tcpdump source repositories](http://www.tcpdump.org/#source), and discuss proposed API additions on the list.  Note that this will require making tcpdump, and various language wrappers, support the new APIs.